# Reference request for when a polynomial has a real factorization

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I looking for references to past results related to the following, probably classical, problem.

> What conditions on a real polynomial of degree $n > 2$ are necessary and sufficient to conclude that it factorizes into the product of real factors of degrees $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_m$?

For example, say I have a sextic equation,
$$ p(x) = Ax^6 + Bx^5 + Cx^4 + Dx^3 + Ex^2 + Fx + G.
$$

I want to find conditions on $A,B,\dots,G$ such that I can be certain that $p(x)$ is the product to 2 real cubic equations (not necessarily finding the factorization of course).  By the fundamental theorem of algebra, we know that there are no conditions on $A,\dots,G$ to conclude that it factorizes as the product of 3 real quadratics.  But it seems nontrivial to ask when it will be the product of a 2 cubics (or maybe it is! Just looking for references or a solution if its actually an easy question).  Similar would be the question of when it has 6 real roots or 6 real linear factors.

Comment: I think the most important information is the number of real roots (and I am certain that this is the only information you need for your problem).  You probably need [Sturm'sTheorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for this.  For example, a sextic polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ can be factorized into two cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if the sextic has at least two real roots.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking it only depends on the real roots, but I hadn't heard of Sturm's theorem, it looks more or less spot on. Thanks!  I'll leave the question open for now to see if others have more references and suggestions.

Comment: If you factor the polynomial as far as you can, you will get one linear factor for each root, and then the rest will be quadratic factors. Any combination of degrees you can build from such factors is possible. Classifying the number of real roots, however, is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I'm looking for the conditions on $(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)$ that ensure there are at least two roots, for example.  Addressing this question for general polynomials would be ideal, and just factoring say a 14th order polynomial as far as I can isn't really my intension, although of course one can try if there was a specific need.  As you noted, it might be (very) hard to tease out these conditions.. though Sturm's theorem may help, not sure yet.